# mulitiindexing in python: how to select level0-index based on multiple values in level1 rows

Tags: pandas, indexing, ipython

I'm working on a multiindex pivot table with 470 columns >7000 rows:

```
    pivot.head()
    Componentnr               1    2      3      4      5      6      7      8
Genename
A2M      Mediancoverage  84.5  281    156    131     11   81.5    251    101
         inhouse3-5       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN     1    NaN    NaN    NaN
A2ML1    Mediancoverage   146  156   4.75  124.5  208.5  111.5  136.5  164.5
         inhouse3-5         5    0      0      0      0      0      0      0
A4GALT   Mediancoverage   165  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    Na
```

I want to select those level-0 index names that have 'Mediancoverage'<20 and 'inhouse3-5'>0 (excl. NaN)  for the same componentnr (=columns).

Thus for the example above the result should be  'A2M' because of column 5

Until know, I managed to select for row in which any value meets the criteria:

```
apply(lambda row: any(i<20 for i in row), axis=1)
apply(lambda row: any(i>=1 for i in row), axis=1)
```

but in this way I don't know if both criteria were met in the same column

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly modified/reformated your data frame example to make it easier to work with:

```
                            1       2       3       4       5       6       7
Genename    Filter                          
A2M         Mediancoverage  84.5    281.0   156.00  131.0   11.0    81.5    251.0
            inhouse3-5      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN
A2ML1       Mediancoverage  146.0   156.0   4.75    124.5   208.5   111.5   136.5
            inhouse3-5      5.0     0.0     0.00    0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

You can use [groupby/apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) here to filter your relevant genes:

```
def filter_gene(sub_df):
    # drop multiindex for easier selection
    sub_df = sub_df.reset_index(0, drop=True)

    # define your filters
    bool_coverage = sub_df.loc["Mediancoverage", :] < 20
    bool_inhouse = sub_df.loc["inhouse3-5", :] > 0

    # if any column fulfills both filter requirements, return True 
    if (bool_coverage & bool_inhouse).any():
        return True

# groupby by gene, apply filter, and remove non-hits
result = df.groupby(level="Genename").apply(filter_gene).dropna().index

print(result)
Index(['A2M'], dtype='object', name='Genename')
```

The idea is simple. You iterate over your genes, apply the filter, and keep those which fulfill your filter requirements.

Comment: I get the error 'the label [Mediancoverage] is not in the index, although it is in the index (second level) after groupby (level='Genename'). Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Where does the error occur? The first index level *Genename* gets dropped within the the `filter_gene` function which allows to access the *Mediancoverage* without using multiIndex-Slicing. The error could also occur in case some genes do not have a row with *Mediancoverage* which poses a new requirement.

Comment: I get the error for the last step( result=....). when I do it step by step, defining filters works but for the if term I get the error _the truth value of an series is ambigious_ . But maybe I do sth wrong, I'm still new to python. I'm sure that all genes have 'Mediancoverage'.

Comment: Sounds like your input data frame is somewhat different from your example given. Does the solution work for you with a minimal dummy data frame like the one I used above?

Comment: sorry, there was an typo in my function. It's working now :)